# Printar valor de um item QTableWidget Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt-5, pyqt

Estou tentando fazer um simples *print* em um valor seja `int` ou `str` de um item (célula) que foi preenchido por mim.

Exemplo:

```
item = self.tablejan_3.item(0, 0)
item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "celulajan"))
```

Já tentei printar da seguinte forma:

```
def testedb (self):
    data = lambda:self.tablefevereiro.currentItem(0,0)
    print(data)
```

Porém retorna o erro

> function salva_dados.testedb.. at 0x0000026680E6DAF0>

Tentei converter o tipo da célula para `int` e `str` e continua a mesma coisa.

Segue a string dentro da célula que quero fazer o *print* no terminal:

[image: a string dentro da celula que quero fazer o print no terminal]

OBS: O *print* no terminal vai acontecer quando eu clicar em um botão já configurado na função `testedb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QTableWidgetItem   **<----**  *QTableWidget::[**currentItem()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#currentItem) const
>
> Returns the current item.

> QString  **<----**  QTableWidgetItem::[**text**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#text)() const
>
> Returns the item's text.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tablejan_3 = QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tablejan_3.setColumnCount(2)
        __qtablewidgetitem = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tablejan_3.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem)
        __qtablewidgetitem1 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tablejan_3.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem1)
        self.tablejan_3.setRowCount(3)
        __qtablewidgetitem2 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tablejan_3.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem2)
        __qtablewidgetitem3 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tablejan_3.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem3)
        __qtablewidgetitem4 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tablejan_3.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, __qtablewidgetitem4)
        self.tablejan_3.setObjectName(u"tablejan_3")
        self.tablejan_3.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(130)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tablejan_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 320, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Click me", None))
        ___qtablewidgetitem = self.tablejan_3.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "DATA", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem1 = self.tablejan_3.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "PLANO", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem2 = self.tablejan_3.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem3 = self.tablejan_3.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem4 = self.tablejan_3.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        ___qtablewidgetitem4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None));
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):   
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText("celulajan")             
        self.tablejan_3.setItem(0, 0, item) 
        
    def button_clicked(self):
        item = self.tablejan_3.currentItem()
        if item:
            print(f'{item.text()}')  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 10, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: voce salvou meu amigo, consegui printar o valor com    def testedb(self):
        data = self.tablefevereiro.item(0,0).text()
        print(data) dessa forma, sem precisar do valor ser selecionado, e agora aprendi aqui com printar se a celula for selecionada, me ajudou muito mesmo, sucesso irmao. obs, nao sei se é aqui que eu respondo.

Answer (score 2):

Sua variável `data` é apenas um `lambda`, isto é, uma função anônima. Você não está executando a função, então o valor printado é o do próprio objeto da função.

Não sei qual era seu intuito a usar `lambda: ...`, mas recomendo fazer da seguinte forma:

```
def testedb(self):
    data = self.tablefevereiro.currentItem().text()
    print(data)
```

O código vai printar o valor da célula que está selecionada na tabela.

Comment: Ainda estou meio perdido nessa biblioteca, mas vc conseguiu me esclarecer. por que o uso do lambda, eu ficava me perguntando kk, muito obrigado ajudou muito, e só faltava mesmo esse .txt() , mais uma vez obrigado, obs, nao sei se é aqui que eu respondo.